# Making a batch script for sfc, DISM Online and Limit Access where it will ask me to paste the path of the offline installation media

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file where I'll have 4 choices to choose from.

Now Number 1 and 2 works flawlessly, however I messed up on number 3 and 4.

This is what I've tried, and I hit a wall I cannot make this to work

```
@echo off

echo 1. SFC Scan Utility
echo 2. DISM [Using Windows Update]
echo 3. DISM [Using Mounted Image]
echo 4. DISM [Using Own Source]

choice /c:123

If errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 goto Sfc
If errorlevel 2 if not errorlevel 3 goto Dism
If errorlevel 3 if not errorlevel 4 goto LAccess
If errorlevel 4 if not errorlevel 5 goto LAccess2
:[Sfc]
echo. & echo  Running [SFC] . . .
              sfc.exe /scannow
:[Dism]
echo. & echo  Running [DISM] . . .
              Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
:[LAccess]
echo. & echo  Running [DISM Limit Access] . . .
              Dism /Image:C:\offline /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:c:\test\mount\windows
:[LAccess2]
echo. & echo  Running [DISM Limit Access] . . .
              Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth  /LimitAccess

echo. & echo ^>Press ANY key to EXIT . . . & pause >nul & Exit;
```

I wanted the batch file to ask me to paste the path [Example: /Source:c:\test\mount\windows] when I'll choose Number 3 or 4 and when I paste the path and press enter it will do the exact same thing like I typed the whole thing manually.

Apologies for using too much third bracket, first bracket on my keyboard doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methodology is simple and readily visible from the built in help and throughout this site's pages.

```bash
@Echo Off

Echo 1. SFC Scan Utility
Echo 2. DISM [Using Windows Update]
Echo 3. DISM [Using Mounted Image]
Echo 4. DISM [Using Own Source]

%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 1234

If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo LAccess2
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo LAccess
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo Dism

:Sfc
Echo(
Echo  Running [SFC] . . .
%SystemRoot%\System32\sfc.exe /scannow
GoTo EndIt

:Dism
Echo(
Echo  Running [DISM] . . .
%SystemRoot%\System32\Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
GoTo EndIt

:LAccess
Echo(
Echo  Running [DISM Limit Access] . . .

:GetImage
Set "Image="
Set /P "Image=Please type the location of your image and press ENTER>" || GoTo GetImage
%SystemRoot%\System32\Dism.exe /Image:C:\offline /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:"%Image%"
GoTo EndIt

:LAccess2
Echo(
Echo  Running [DISM Limit Access] . . .

:GetSource
Set "Source="
Set /P "Source=Please type the location of your source and press ENTER>" || GoTo GetSource
%SystemRoot%\System32\Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:"%Source%" /LimitAccess

:EndIt
Echo(
Echo ^>Press ANY key to EXIT . . .
Pause 1>NUL
```

Comment: I'm using bat to exe converter to make an exe file out of it, however it does not allow me to run it. It always says "Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service."

When running the batch file it works but when converting it to exe, it gives me the error.

Comment: I don't care! I've answered your question, if you want to use a pointless and problematic program on it, (in order to hide it inside an extractable archive), that's your problem, not mine, or this answers'.

Comment: Why are you getting angry about it? I just want to learn. the code that you helped me with it works flawlessly, and thank you so much for that. My apologies if I've offended you somehow. I'm new to this forum and I registered because I had a question regarding that batch file of mine.

Comment: You asked a question, about that batch file of yours, I answered it, and you admitted it works as intended. Now, for some reason, despite you not having even accepted my answer, you seem to think I'm here to assist you with another question entirely. That question is specific to your Operating System software and/or a particular piece of third party software you have used. Software questions are off topic on this site.

Comment: There is some miscommunication going on. I do accept your answer mate, like I said before it works flawlessly, and thanks again for your help. I was not aware that software questions are off topic here. You answered my query and my issue with that batch file is resolved.

Comment: okay I get it now. its like when my teacher asks me a question and I give the correct answer, she gives me a cookie. I like this concept very much. gave you your metaphorical cookie. Cheers.
Unfortunately I cannot vote up cause I'm new to this site and it seems I do not have the permission to do that.